# Do tools for generating documentation of PostgreSQL data warehouses/databases exist?

Tags: database, documentation-generator, postgresql

Something like [Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/) but for SQL, so we could document table structures and relationships in a series of web pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A colleague mentioned [PostgreSQL Autodoc](https://github.com/cbbrowne/autodoc)

> This is a utility which will run through PostgreSQL system tables and returns HTML, DOT, and several styles of XML which describe the database.
>
> As a result, documentation about a project can be generated quickly and be automatically updatable, yet have a quite professional look if you do some DSSSL/CSS work.

It allows specifying schemas and tables, and can even process comments on objects in different markup languages (e.g. markdown) using specified translating executables.

Answer (score 0):

A different colleague has recommended [Amundsen](https://www.amundsen.io/amundsen/) as a more general purpose data documentation engine, which has a [PostgreSQL metadata extractor](https://github.com/amundsen-io/amundsendatabuilder/blob/master/databuilder/extractor/postgres_metadata_extractor.py):

> Amundsen is a data discovery and metadata engine for improving the productivity of data analysts, data scientists and engineers when interacting with data. It does that today by indexing data resources (tables, dashboards, streams, etc.) and powering a page-rank style search based on usage patterns (e.g. highly queried tables show up earlier than less queried tables). Think of it as Google search for data.